# Override Django Admin Landing Page

Tags: django, url, admin

I am creating a custom django admin.

I am trying to have it so that when a user logs into /admin they are directed to /admin/database (the *app* admin rather than the *projects*). I have worked overriding "index.html" with "base_site.html". This works somewhat, however, I cannot completely edit the main django-admin template so it just focuses on the apps and its causing issues for my project.

**Logging out issues:** After logging out, when navigating to 'admin/database', I can still see the contents of the page, but when clicking on a "action" link (such as change password), it prompts to login.

I think I'm fudging up the templates somehow. *I want to entirely replace the django admin landing page with the custom one I built at "admin/database/index.html"*

```
path('admin/database/', include('database.urls')),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

Conceptually I would like 'admin' to point to 'admin/database' with full admin functionality. I tried deleting 'admin/', admin.site.urls and it threw an error.